# What is $[mx][my]$ equal to?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is with respect to congruence classes in $\Bbb Z_n$. I know for two congruence classes $[x]$ and $[y]$ that $[x][y] = [xy]$, but for some natural number $m \ge 1$, is $[mx][my] = [m^2xy]$ or $= [mxy]$? I'm having a bit of trouble articulating why this is unclear to me.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: You said that $[a][b]=[ab]$, so $[mx][my] = [(mx)(my)] = [m^2xy]$. I don't see why $[mx][my]$ should be equal to $[mxy]$.

Comment: @azif00 So as I was trying to explain to you the overarching math problem I was trying to solve, where [mx][my] = [mxy] would be a necessary part of the proof, I realized my error in solving the problem. 

I was trying to show that for $G = (Z_n, +)$, for $m \geq 1$, $[x] \in G$, and $\phi: G \rightarrow G$, $\phi_m([x]) = m[x] = [mx]$ is a homomorphism. My mistake was using multiplication instead of addition in showing the homomorphism. It doesn't work with multiplication of course, but it's straightforward with addition. But yeah, you're right, there is no reason [mx][my] would equal [mxy]